# SSIS: How to programmatically delete all files in a given folder?

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I would like do this  in a script task.  For example i would like to be able to do something like this:

```
For each file as file in strDirectory
 file.delete
next file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles(strDirectory)
    File.Delete(file)
Next
```

Comment: Ooh.  You beat me by 13 seconds.  :-)

Comment: Also, I wrote it in VB.NET, which (according to the question tags) is the language the OP is using.  :P

Answer (score 7):

Why do this in a script task? The File System task has the ability to Delete Directory Content without having to program a Script Task.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.IO;

foreach (FileInfo f in new DirectoryInfo("c:\dir").GetFiles())
     f.Delete();
```